# Clarification regarding File Read/Write speed

Tags: c#, .net, windows

In the [research](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64538/tr-2004-136.doc) about IO performances (Section 8, Page 5) - the following has been mentioned:

> Specifically, the overhead stabilizes at around 5 cycles per byte for
>   writes and 10 cycles per byte for reads at request sizes of 64 KB. 
>   This suggests that a dual 2 GHz cpu like the one benchmarked here
>   could sustain over 1GBps of file activity

I am trying to make sense of the math here and can't figure out how "over 1GBps" is derived:

```
2 (dual) x 2 GHz (Gig Cycles/Sec) / 5 Cycles/Byte = 0.8 GB/sec Write Speed
2 (dual) x 2 GHz (Gig Cycles/Sec) / 10 Cycles/Byte = 0.4 GB/sec Read Speed
```

Is my math correct?

Comment: `0.4 + 0.8 > 1.0`  I think by `file activity` they mean both r/w combined.